# Emacs Tramp connection fails with "no such directory"

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I'm hoping to use Tramp mode to edit files on a remote Linux machine, so I open a file like this:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:hwolff@<host>:/home/hwolff/temp.txt
```

But there is no prompt for a password, and saving the file brings the error "no such directory".  Emacs seems to be treating the file path as if it's local, rather than attempting to connect to the remote machine.  I can SSH to that machine with no problems.

Following the SO discussion [Emacs Tramp unable to open directory at times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856399/emacs-tramp-unable-to-open-directory-at-times), I tried turning on tramp-debug-buffer, but no debug buffer ever appeared.

Relevant lines from the *Messages* buffer:

```
Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
...
Saving file /ssh:hwolff@<host>:/home/hwolff/temp.txt...
ad-Orig-error: /ssh:hwolff@<host>:/home/hwolff/: no such directory
```

I loaded Tramp like this:

```
(load-file "/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/net/tramp.elc")
```

That seemed to work fine, and Emacs seems to report that Tramp is ready:

```
M-x tramp-version
2.1.10
```

I'm running Emacs 23.3.1 as Aquamacs on Mac OS 10.7.5:

```
GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, NS apple-appkit-949.54)
of 2011-03-18 on braeburn.aquamacs.org - Aquamacs Distribution 2.2
```